# Using a TextChanged event handler when searching in a database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Not really a code specific question, but rather a way of designing a search functionality.

I have a search field that alters a SQL query depending on the content in my search box. The query, by default, is `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = '(content of search box)'`. This is sent to a `DataTable`and presented to the user in a `DataGridView`.

The search update is currently triggered by a `Button.Click`handler, but how would it be to use a `mySearchField.TextChanged` instead? That would run a new SQL query to the database return a new `DataTable` whenever the content in the search field instead.

Would this impact the database unnecessarily much?

Comment: How many records are there in my_table?

Comment: @AlexB most of the tables I'm using are no more than 20 rows.

Comment: In that case I would load all data at once, store it in a DataTable and use a RowFilter on it after the TextChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on the number of rows in the table have and the number of users who will use the application site. If the number of rows is not excessive, you can load all the data in the DataTable and search using the RowFilter property. In this way you avoid excessive use of the database.
Another option is to establish a minimum of characters to search in database, thus the number queries made to the database is reduced.